# Relative Path Issue Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have the following properties file

> fileLocation=C:\Users\Desktop\SomeFolder
>   tickerNames=C:\Users\Desktop\SomeFile.txt

which I access like

```
 Properties configProp = new Properties();
        String propertyValue = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = PropertyGet.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");
            configProp.load(in);
            propertyValue = configProp.getProperty(propertyName);
```

No matter what I try, when i create a runnable jar file it just will not pick up the file locations. How do i need to structure the files so that my runnable jar can find them?

Thanks

Comment: What does the fileLocation property have to do with the String passed to getResourceAsStream()?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to load it as "/application.properties", it will be loaded from the root of the classpath. That will succeed if you package your properties file into the executable jar you are building.

If you want to side-load the properties file eg. from the same dir as your jar, you can specify a classpath when starting your jar file and make sure the directory gets included where the properties file is.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to put the .properties file in your jar, in resources.